# Каких прав не хватает при подключении к БД Oracle? recursive SQL Level 1, insufficient privileges

Tags: sql, oracle

Использую `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production`

Создаю пользователя `user_name` так:

```
create user user_name identified by user_pass21;
grant connect to user_name;
grant create session to user_name;
grant alter session to user_name; 
grant unlimited tablespace to user_name;
```

При подключении получаю ошибку:

> Could not logon as user_name@sid
>
> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL Level 1
>
> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>
> ORA-06512: at line 2

В БД создано 4 триггера на `Logon`. При отключении одного из них, ошибка уходит.

Код проблемного триггера:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_session
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'alter session set events ''10046 trace name context forever, level 12''';
END log_session;
```

Подскажите, каких прав не хватает и как их добавить(или как по другому исправить ошибку) ?

**UPD:**

Если подключиться при отключенном триггере, то команда `alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12'` выполняется без ошибок.

**UPD2:**

Если создать триггер под пользователем `sys`, то логон работает. Какие права тогда надо добавить пользователю создающему триггер?

Comment: Почему-то не получилось воспроизвести. Возникает ли ошибка если остальные три триггера отключить, а этот оставить? Воспроизводиться ли ошибка на чистой БД?

Comment: А кто триггер создаёт?

Comment: @defaultlocale поставить чистую БД сейчас нет возможности. Если остальные тригеры отключить, а этот оставить, ошибка возникает.

Comment: @0xdb один из служебных пользователей системы. Оказалось, что если создать такой же тригер под `sys`, то логон проходит успешно. Вопрос по прежнему актуален, а какие тогда права нужны создающему триггер?)

Comment: `alter session` как минимум необходимо. Триггер же выполняется под его именем.

Comment: `alter session` есть

Comment: Значит он получил это право по `rule`,  должно быть напрямую, т.е. `grant`.

Comment: Действительно. Выдал грантом напрямую, все заработало. Оформите ответом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Триггер выполняется под именем и с правами пользователя, который создал триггер. Причём правa, которые им унаследованы из ролей (`grant role_name to user_name`) не действуют в теле триггера (а так же в хранимых фунциях или процедурах).

Другими словами, в именных объектах, унаследованные через выделеные роли права, не действуют.

Необходимые права должны быть даны напрямую пользователю, который будет владельцем создаваемого объекта, т.е `grant <privilege> to <owner user_name>`.

На примере триггера:

```
SQL>    conn / as sysdba
Connected.

    create role common_role;
Role created.

    grant create session, alter session, create trigger, create procedure, administer database trigger to common_role;
Grant succeeded.

    create user common_user identified by common default tablespace users;
User created.

    grant common_role TO common_user;
Grant succeeded.

    create user worker_user identified by worker default tablespace users;
User created.

    grant create session to worker_user;
Grant succeeded.

    connect common_user/common
Connected.

    create or replace trigger common_on_logon
    after logon on database
    begin
        execute immediate 'alter session set sql_trace = true';
     end;
     /
Trigger created.

SQL>     conn worker_user/worker
```

> ERROR:
>   ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>   ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>   ORA-06512: at line 2

Дадим права напрямую, и будет работать:

```
SQL>   conn / as sysdba
Connected.
    grant alter session to common_user;
Grant succeeded.

SQL>     conn worker_user/worker
Connected.
```

Убедительно показывает недействительность унаследованных через роли прав показывает такой пример:

```
connect common_user/common

create function list_session_roles return varchar2 is
    ret varchar(1024);
begin
    for r in (select * from session_roles) loop ret := ret||','||r.role; end loop;
    return trim(ret,',');
end;
/

-- так роли видны 
select * from session_roles;
ROLE
------------------------------
COMMON_ROLE

-- именной объект, ролей не видно 
select coalesce(list_session_roles, 'none') "roles" from dual;
roles
--------------
none

-- не именной объект, роли видны
variable ret varchar2(1024)
begin for r in (select * from session_roles) loop :ret := trim(:ret||','||r.role,','); end loop; end;
/
print ret
RET
------------
COMMON_ROLE
```

Посмотреть, какие права даны напрямую, а какие унаследованны от ролей можно так:

```
select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee in ('PUBLIC','COMMON_USER');

GRANTEE                        PRIVILEGE                                ADM
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ---
COMMON_USER                    ALTER SESSION                            NO

select *
from dba_sys_privs
where grantee in (
    select granted_role
    from dba_role_privs
    where grantee = 'COMMON_USER'
    );

GRANTEE                        PRIVILEGE                                ADM
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ---
COMMON_ROLE                    ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER              NO
COMMON_ROLE                    CREATE PROCEDURE                         NO
COMMON_ROLE                    ALTER SESSION                            NO
COMMON_ROLE                    CREATE TRIGGER                           NO
COMMON_ROLE                    CREATE SESSION                           NO
```